# Which is more efficient: redirecting to an image,or pushing the image through php?

Tags: php, image, performance, redirect

An external party has to use the dynamicly generated images that are used on our site. For that, I created a function that serves the image through a url. E.g. http://test.com/image/$code/$width/$height. So, it finds the image with code $code, resizes it to $width and $height, and then serves the image itself (not the url). The external party can now use `<img src="http://test.com/image/$code/$width/$height" />`

This is working fine, but of course this is a quite a hit on the server every time it is used, especially if the image is used in newsletters that are sent to 1000s of people.

I can make it a little more efficient by checking if the image is already existing and then returning it without generating it first, of course. But I was also looking at redirection.

So, basically, my question is if it is more efficient to generate/load the image and then serve it, or doing a 301 redirect to the actual image. I know that this also has some drawbacks, most notably needing two requests per image, but I am wondering how that compares to pushing an entire image through php and the image generation process.

**Update:**

Maybe I should clarify things a bit.

1. I am interested in server load, not so much in UX. Most probably the latter is worse off by redirecting, as it does the double amount of server requests).
2. The difference in the two situations is as follows:

Image generation situation:

```
- Check if image exists. If not, generate.
- Then do this

$path       = BASE_PATH."/".$image->Filename;
$mimetype   = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($path));

header("Content-type: ".$mimetype);
echo readfile($path);
die;
```

Image redirect situation:

```
- Check if image exists. If not, generate.
- Then do this

$location   = BASE_HREF."/".$image->Filename;
$mimetype   = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($path));
header('Location: '.$location,true,301); //or maybe a 303 (other)
die;
```

Obviously, in the second situation php has to do less and apache more (serve 2 files instead of one). In the first situation apache has to do more and php less. So the question is, is the extra work that php has to do more or less than the extra work that Apache has to do?

Comment: I would pre process all the images into 3 different sizes, then create folders for them with the code/width/height. And then direct straight to the image.  That way its fast, and theres choices between thumbnails, small, large etc

Comment: The image sizes are changing a lot, so this is not a viable option, unfortunately.

Comment: Ahhh...then you've answered your own question right there.  You don't really have any other choice but to generate and load

Comment: What exactly do you mean "more efficient"?  Do you mean "seems faster to the user" or do you mean "less load on the server" or do you mean something else?  "More efficient" is vague.

Comment: why don't you create 3 sizes. small (mobile), medium (low-res), big (hi-res). In HTML (newsletter or whatever) you just scale proportional the image which is the closest to the desired size with (width/height property) imho there's no need to make things more complicated than neccessary ?

Comment: @KyleK Yes, we are generating the images. It is not the generating performance that interests me, but the difference between redirection and serving through php (see update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is critical that you check to see if the image already exists before you generate the thing. It isn't going to help "a little." Creating a .jpg is a *lot* more expensive than checking for a filename.

The rest of your question isn't completely clear to me, but I'll try for an answer anyway.

301 redirects aren't generally used for what you're talking about. They're to tell a search spider that a page has moved permanently. Functionally, it doesn't work any differently than a regular redirect.

Moving on, I'm even more confused. "and then serves the image itself (not the url)"

Servers pretty much always serve both. The url tells it which file to send and then it sends the binary data it finds at that URL. And files are always saved somewhere, even if it's just a tmp folder where it will be deleted. Unless you've done something exotic, in which case, ask yourself why you did that.

If the image will never be used again (not even if the same user re-vists the same page) simply send the remote server a link to where the lives in the temporary folder on your server after the image was created. If the image *might* be re-used, save it somewhere. The local server would be easier and the extra request by the remote won't slow things down a noticeable amount.

Comment: I think I was confused on your requirements, so I'm going to restate.

Comment: Ahh, damn. Tried to edit, failed. I'll try again.

I understand your question a lot better now. I don't know what the answer to your direct question would be. Probably the PHP headers will be faster though I don't think either route will make much difference. The real cost is in the image generation.

I'm still a little confused on the rest. If some of the images already exist, then you are assuming they will be reused. Yet the rest of the script seems to be built around the assumption that the images are only useful once.

Comment: The images are used only once, per newsletter, but a lot of different newsletters are sent with different layouts. So yes, a lot of people are seeing the same image, but after it is used once, it will never be sent. 

Also, the option of generating a lot of images in advance is possible, but at present takes to much time, as the framework used does not support that out of the box. If we experience performance problems, that would -  I think - be the first course of action.

This question more or less is one out of curiosity, and not out of necessity. At present I think the server can handle it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but my gut feeling is that if you're already running a PHP script, then the additional cost of writing some headers and calling [`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) will be trivial.

More importantly, is the file going to be used more than once by the same user?
If so, you could benefit significantly by making the file cacheable. If you redirect to a static file, the web server will automatically take care of the caching. If you serve the file through PHP, you will have to cache it yourself.

To do this, you need to:

- Compute a Last-Modified date or an ETag (unique ID).
- Check the request headers for an `If-Modified-Since:` or `If-None-Match:` header.
- Compare the header values against the computed date or ETag.
- If your file is newer or doesn't match the ETag (or the request headers don't exist), send a `200` response including the file.
- Otherwise, send a `304` response without the file.
- In both cases, send the current `Last-Modified:` or `ETag` header, and maybe a sensible `Expires:` header.

Comment: Nice point about the caching! In my situation, a file probably won't be accessed many times by the same user, but it is most definately something to take into account.